# Django talking to multiple servers

Tags: python, django, database, celery, scheduled-tasks

There's a lot of info out there and honestly it's a bit too much to digest and I'm a bit lost.

My web app has to do so some very resource intensive tasks. Standard setup right now app on server static / media on another for hosting. What I would like to do is setup celery so I can call `task.delay` for these resource intensive tasks.

- I'd like to dedicate the resources of entire separate servers to these resource intensive tasks.

**Here's the question:** How do I setup celery in this way so that from my main server (where the app is hosted) the calls for `.delay` are sent from the apps to these servers?

**Note:** These functions will be kicking data back to the database / affecting models so data integrity is important here. So, how does the data (assuming the above is possible...) retrieved get sent back to the database from the seperate servers while preserving integrity?

1. Is this possible and if so wth do I begin - information overload?
2. If not what should I be doing / what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of Celery is to work in exactly this way, ie as a distributed task server. You can spin up workers on as many machines as you like, and the broker - ie rabbitmq - will distribute them as necessary.

I'm not sure what you're asking about data integrity, though. Data doesn't get "sent back" to the database; the workers connect directly to the database in exactly the same way as the rest of your Django code.

Comment: Right should have clarified it's "spinning up the workers..." On different machines bit I'm having trouble with. Do I just set the brokers for each specific apps / task to point to this server? As for data... A cron job will be running scraping data to update models and the initial data scraped will also be deferred. What I meant was is passing a model instance and then calling delay to update it through celery tasks going to be a problem.

Comment: I'm still not quite sure what you're asking. You don't have brokers for specific apps; you have one broker, and multiple workers, but each worker usually has a complete copy of the code and can run any task. On the data, you shouldn't pass instances around, but IDs; your task code would get the instance from the db by id, update it, then save it back.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Would you have a link to a reference / tutorial for setting up the broker and workers? As is probably obvious by from the question / comments no idea what I'm doing.